# Declaration custom element in html without code behind in the Polymer library

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Can I declare custom element only in a html-file without a dart-code behind (.dart file) in the Polymer library?

I would like to have only a html markup of custom element. Also the markup may contains some inline dart-code (for example, an initialization code and events handling methods). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

not tested but I think it should work

```dart
<polymer-element name='my-element'>
  <template>
    <div>some content</div>
    <button on-click='{{clickHandler}}'>click me</button>
  </template>
  <script type='application/dart'>
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('my-element') 
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  MyElement.created() : super.created();

  void clickHandler(Event e) {
    print(e.target.toString());
  }
}

  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**EDIT END**

Just add the attribute `noscript`.

```dart
<polymer-element name='my-element' noscript>
  <template>
    <div>some content</div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

In Dart inheriting from such a component (`<polymer-element name='my-other-element' extends='my-element>...`) doesn't work well especially if the derived element has an associated Dart class (works fine in Polymer.js).

Comment: Günter, thanks a lot! It works! Could you please complement your answer by code example of an event-handling using an inline dart-code in the html-page (if it is possible).

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. I thought the question was about a polymer element without code, an now you want inline code?
Inline code is just a different way to organize your files. There are no limitations to what you can do with inlined code (beside a worse developer experience). I advise against it. What's your reason to inline the code into the HTML file?

Comment: My question is about how to declare a custom element without .dart file as well. I have many small custom elements. I don't want to create two files for each element (.html and .dart). I know that generally this is worse developer experience. But not in my case.

Comment: I haven't used this yet but as far as I know you just put the code inside the `<script type='application/dart'>your code here </script>` instead of the `src` attribut that refers the `*.dart` file.
You should update your question to make it more clear what you want to know.